# Converting Javascript DOM function into REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I am currently learning React JS and want to convert one of my vanilla JS projects into React. However, I do not know convert functions using JS DOM functions (I know you should not use this in React) into more REACT JS appropriate function.

```
function getRandom(letters) {
    var randomSet = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    //console.log("set random", randomSet);
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = randomSet;
    _timer = setTimeout(() => getRandom(letters), 1000);
  }
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Don't think of it in terms of "converting functions to React".  Instead, *implement the desired functionality* in React.  In this case it looks like you'd have some state value to output in the rendering, and a function you'd invoke which fetches a random element from an array and updates that state value.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const [randomLetter, setRandomLetter] = useState();

  const getRandomLetters = (letters) => {
    const randomSet = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    setRandomLetter(randomSet);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
      const randomLetterInterval = setInterval(() => {
        getRandomLetters(letters)
      }, 1000);

      return () => {
        clearInterval(randomLetterInterval);
      }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>{randomLetter}</>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class MyFirstComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { rndNum: null, offOn: true };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getRandom("Hello-React");
  }

  getRandom = (letters) => {
    var randomSet = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    //console.log("set random", randomSet);
    this.setState({ rndNum: randomSet });
    // document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = randomSet;
    if (this.state.offOn) {
      setTimeout(() => this.getRandom(letters), 1000);
    }
  };

  OffOn = () => {
    this.setState({ offOn: !this.state.offOn });
    if (!this.state.offOn) {
      this.getRandom("Hello-React");
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.rndNum}</h2>
        <button onClick={this.OffOn}>Start/Stop</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<MyFirstComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-forked-x7pzk8?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

In React state informs how a component is rendered. When the state changes, a new render is performed.

1. At least one state for the updated random letter. In this example I've also added a state for the array of letters I'm passing into the function.
2. [Using `useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to call the randomise function [with a `setTimeout`](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/settimeout-in-react-components-using-hooks) when the component is initially rendered.
3. `getRandom` sets a new state for the letter, the component renders again, and that letter is displayed.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example({ data }) {

  // Initialise the states
  const [ letters, setLetters ] = useState(data);
  const [ letter, setLetter ] = useState('Waiting for random letter');

  // Set the new state with a random letter
  function getRandom() {
    const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
    setLetter(letters[rnd]);
  }

  // Use a useEffect to call the function
  // on the first render
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(getRandom, 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{letter}</p>
    </div>
  );

}

// Just creating an array of letters
const arr = Array.from(Array(26)).map((e, i) => i + 65);
const letters = arr.map((x) => String.fromCharCode(x));

// Passing in that array as a component prop
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={letters} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```